# How to pass the data as params in the route using window.open in angular8

Tags: angular, url-routing, angular-routing, angular-router

i have listing page in which based on click of edit or view, it should open in the new tab the profile page. So i have used `window.open('/profile'+'/' + data.group + '/' + data.profile + '/' + mode,'_blank')` in the listing page on click of edit or view button. so here i had also given which mode i had clicked, whether it is `edit or view. So as on click of multiple users multiple tab must be opened along with the data and mode, i had thought of approaching a method where in i can pass the data and mode as params in the url.
But after this i am struck, not getting how to go forward.
here from the url params how can i fetch the id's and mode.

```
http://localhost:4200/profile/101/101/ro
```

here

Ts:

```
public editAgent(data, mode) {
    this.selected = { data, mode };
    window.open('/profile'+'/' + data.group + '/' + data.profile + '/' + mode,'_blank')
  }
```

Routing of profile page:

```
{
        path: '', component:ProfileComponent
    }
```

In home page i had given profile page routing like this:

```
const homeRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: "", component: HomeComponent ,
   children: [
    { path: 'profile/:id/:id/:mode', loadChildren: () => import('../profile/profile.module').then(m => m.ProfileModule) }
  ] }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular router provides a activedRoute service. 
https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#params

You can inject into your ProfileComponent.

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
  this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
  });
}
```